Altair Impute is not working for aggregate data over time
alt.Chart(cars).mark_line().encode(
    x='year(Year):T',
    y=alt.Y('mean(Miles_per_Gallon):Q').impute(value=0)
)

Output Image
The above code does not impute zero for the year 1981.
I tried other approaches such as using the transform_impute() method. But I had no luck so far. I am using Altair version 5.0. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

To begin with, does 1981 exist in the data, and if it is the data provided by altair, then 1981 does not exist. A more detailed explanation is needed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
